# Store data whilst logging with PHP and Forms

Tags: php, forms, authentication, submit, store

I have a booking form that submits the chosen information to a PHP file that displays it in style with the theme on the left. The user then has the option to log in or register on the right hand side.

The problem is that if they log in or register the information that was submitted by the form to the PHP file is not there once the form submitted for signing in is complete.

I am well aware of the reason why, the question however is how to get around it.

Submitting the form data again with the log in form would be the best option but I cannot locate the file that the form submits to. The url is, `?action=login&#038;instance=1` and `?action=register&#038;instance=1` respectively. Any ideas chaps.

I will provide you with the link for the working example, however it is rather long winded as you have to submit certain forms to get there. Go To [www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/adveture-training](http://www.divethegap.com/update/diving-trips/adveture-training) Then CLICK on beginners, choose anyone of the dates you see and press continue. Then you are there.

Many Thanks,

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Why not just store the data from the first form in a `$_SESSION` variable?  This is the cleanest, most flexible, and easiest way to pass data between multiple unrelated pages, especially when the data changes.  Here's the general process.

1. Get variables from form 1 (adventure training form?)
2. Do normal form actions (validation, whatever
3. Put form variables into `$_SESSION` (e.g.: `$_SESSION['tmp']['adventure-training-form'] = array('somefield' => $blah, 'someotherfield' => $foo, 'etc' => $yaddayadda);`)
4. User either *logs in* or *registers*.
5. At the end of either process from step 4, get data from `$_SESSION['tmp']['adventure-training-form']` and do whatever you need with it

Comment: I have never worked with sessions before. I have just been reading up on them now. Do I take it that I would put all the data I wanted as the value of an input and store that or can I put any element's content in.

Comment: OK I will give it a try. I take it that separating the variables back on the final page would be to post <?php
  $blah = $_POST["blah"]; ?> etc...

Comment: DOES the session have to go above <html>

Comment: The only restriction is that `session_start()` has to be executed before any output is sent (any `echo`, `print`, html output, etc).  Read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php if you haven't already.